# concatenate function name and run function

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a small class called MyCar()

```
class MyCar():    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def engine_start(self):
        print("my car's name is " + self.name)
```

Then I have created 4 objects of the class.

```
c1 = MyCar("corolla")
c2 = MyCar("civic")
c3 = MyCar("coroll")
c4 = MyCar("civi")
```

Works perfectly fine. When i run the function for the 1st class, it gives me the desired outout:

```
 c1.engine_start(): 'my car's name is corolla'
```

I want to use a for-loop and run the function for each of the instances i have created of the class.

Comment: Place all your instances in a list and call `engine_start()` for each instance of that list.

Comment: You can actually create a list of your car objects from the list of car names. Check my answer below @user3740943

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of cars:

```
cars = [c1, c2, c3, c4]
for car in cars:
    car.engine_start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a list of parameters, and create a list of class instances from them
. Then you can use that list to call your functions

```
#List of names
names = ["corolla", "civic", "coroll", "civi"]

#List of instances of class MyCar
cars = [ MyCar(item) for item in names]

#Iterate through the list and call the function
for c in cars:
    c.engine_start()
```

The output is

```
my car's name is corolla
my car's name is civic
my car's name is coroll
my car's name is civi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a list for car's name, add this code after the class:

```
car_names=['corolla','civic','coroll','civi']
for i in range(len(car_names)):
    MyCar(car_names[i]).engine_start()
```

Output:

```
my car's name is corolla
my car's name is civic
my car's name is coroll
my car's name is civi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dictionary to store the var_name to value mapping and call the class whenever you require:

```
def call_fun(input_dict):
    for car in input_dict: 
        return MyCar(input_dict[car])

input_dict = {"c1":"corolla","c2":"civic","c3":"coroll","c4":"civi"}
call_fun(input_dict)
```